# How to use Chef Tracking Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-plugins

I have a chef workstation setup on my Jenkins machine and currently use a "execute shell" in jenkins to run a shell script which runs knife bootstrap commands (for configuring nodes) .I have already installed the chef tracking plugin, but dont know how to use it for "tracking when/where/what files are deployed". i.e Can I use this plugin in my setup ? If yes, how do I use it in a jenkins job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Chef Tracking Plugin wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Chef+Tracking+Plugin):

> *Recognized resource type*
>   This plugin currently tracks the use of file resource and all its subtypes.

So you have to download the files from jenkins within Chef using e.g. the [remote_file](http://docs.chef.io/resources.html#remote-file) resource.

Don't forget to install the [chef-handler-jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/chef-handler-jenkins) report handler, which then reports back about the usage.

Comment: Other than that, as your question is quite broad (and it seems you didn't follow the instructions in the wiki, yet), please be more specific about your problems.